# Two paragraph overlay an image

Tags: html, css, overlay

Hy guys!
At the end of my project I have "Oferte speciale" ..

I want that "Esspresso lung
Ando's food" to overlay the image on the top and "4lei in loc de 7lei " on the bottom .Like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me ?
Demo : http://kilometri.ro/brasovtour/bvtour

Comment: create a div for that give it more z-index in css property

Answer (score 1):

Replace your css with this css :

```
.top-text {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 5px;
    line-height: 0.923;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    width: 135px;
}
.oferta {
    border: 2px solid #BFBFBF;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-width: 145px;
    min-height: 145px;
    position: relative;
}
.bottom-text {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    line-height: 0.923;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    width: 135px;
}
```

**NOTE** : Always include your code while asking question SO.

Answer (score 0):

**Now try this css**

```
.oferta {
position: relative;
width: 145px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.top-text {
background-color: #ffffff;
opacity: 0.7;
line-height: 0.923;
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
left: 3px;
right: 3px;
top: 3px;
}
.bottom-text {
background-color: #ffffff;
opacity: 0.7;
line-height: 0.923;
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
bottom: 3px;
left: 3px;
right: 3px;
}
.oferta img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your can try this examples it's usefull for you

http://codeoverkill.com/question/image-overlay-between-2-paragraph/